# A grammar for Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, grammar

Does a grammar (like in EBNF or similar format) exist for MS Access SQL syntax? Like how TSQL syntax is documented with EBNF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

I have only been able to find find tutorials with examples, but not a full grammar.

Comment: ms-access supports (at least some) vba functions, which is what I suspect would be the hardest parts to translate to T-SQL. However, as it is now, this question is too broad for SO and given your reputation you should already know this. Try to be more specific.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Why is it too broad? I'm asking about something like a EBNF grammar. That is a very specific request. It such a thing does not exist, just say so, that would be a valid answer.

Comment: How about official manual? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Queries-93fb69b7-cfc1-4f3e-ab56-b0a01523bb50#ID0EAABAAA=SQL_syntax

Comment: IMHO, it's too broad because it can't be answered within the scope of a single SO post. There are just too many differences between ms-access sql dialect and t-sql. Another option is that you are requesting the help of the community to locate an off-site reference which is also off-topic ("
Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...") Either way, this question, as it is, is not a good fit to stackoverflow. This doesn't mean it's a bad question, it's just not the place for it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I'm not asking for *differences* to T-SQL. The grammar of T-SQL is well documented (For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so that is not an issue. I'm asking about the grammar of MS Access SQL.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: And I'm not asking for documentation of VBA functions either. That is outside the scope of a grammar.

Comment: Well, I do hope you would get an answer for your question, but I personally still think it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the full Access SQL reference [here on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-access-sql-reference).

Note that some statements are exclusive to the SQL server compatible syntax (anything with the `DECIMAL` type and `CHECK` constraints), and this isn't properly described in the reference.

It isn't as extensive and well-written as the T-SQL stuff, but it's closest to what you're asking.